# Communities and household contact

Tags: community, account, contact, npsp, nonprofit-starter-pack

I am currently working in a Communities environment using the NonProfit Success Pack and had a question.
Will creating a contact also create a 1:1 Household contact?

Comment: What is household contact? Is it specific to your project>?

Comment: Are you using the Nonprofit Success Pack?

Comment: @DavidReed Yes sir, I am using the Nonprofit Success Pack.

Comment: Note that in NPSP terminology, "1:1 account" is not the same as "Household account".  FYI, your best resource for NPSP support is the [Power of Us](https://powerofus.force.com) community that is run the Salesforce Foundation.  Lots of participation from users, consultants and Foundation staff, and plenty of documentation links as well.

Answer (score 2):

In a Nonprofit Success Pack context, the answer depends on the [Account Model](https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/NPSP-What-is-an-Account-Model) in which you are operating.

New installs of the NPSP use the Household Account Model. In this model, creating a Contact which is not associated with an Account at the time of creation will result in the NPSP automatically creating a Household Account and associating the Contact to that Household Account.

> You create a Household Account by creating a contact in Salesforce. That is to say, whenever you create a Contact record, Salesforce automatically creates a Household for you.

You would also see an Account record being created if you are using the NPSP's older 1-to-1 Account Model. The Household is a separate object in the 1-to-1 Account Model.